# bash variable expansion ${var:+"..."} in here-document removing double quotes?

Tags: bash, heredoc, expansion, quoting

I'm trying to understand why Bash removes double quotes (but not single quotes) when doing variable expansion with `${parameter:+word}` (*Use Alternate Value*), in a here-document, for example:

```
% var=1
% cat <<EOF
> ${var:+"Hi there"}
> ${var:+'Bye'}
> EOF
Hi there
'Bye'
```

According to the manual, the "word" after `:+` is processed with tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.  None of these should do anything.

What am I missing?  How can I get double quotes in the expansion?

Comment: Seems like a bug or implementation leaking. It's impossible to use a double quote as an alternate value without assigning it to a variable: `dq='"' ; ... ${var:+$dq}`

Comment: @choroba: `${var:+$(echo '"')}` But I basically agree. There is something quite strange in the parsing of `word` in quoted parameter expansions (parameter expansions in here docs are expanded as though quoted, according to the manual, and that seems to be the case.)

Comment: The almost-equivalent of a here document can be seen as an echo "...", and in this case, the " are removed just by typing `echo "${var:+"Hi there"}"` on the command prompt. They come back when using \" but the HERE document is not consistent and produces the \" on output instead of ". Something is clearly not correct.

Answer (score 15):

**tl;dr**

```
$ var=1; cat <<EOF
"${var:+Hi there}"
${var:+$(printf %s '"Hi there"')}
EOF

"Hi there"
"Hi there"
```

The above demonstrates two pragmatic workarounds to include double quotes in the alternative value.
The embedded `$(...)` approach is more cumbersome, but more flexible: it allows inclusion of *embedded* double quotes and also gives you control over whether the value should be expanded or not.

---

[Jens' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099378/45375) and [Patryk Obara's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112262/45375) both shed light on and further demonstrate the problem.

Note that the **problematic behavior equally applies to**:

- (as noted in the other answers) regular **double-quoted strings** (e.g., `echo "${var:+"Hi there"}"`; for the 1st workaround, you'd have to `\`-quote surrounding `"` instances; e.g., `echo "\"${var:+Hi there}\""`; curiously, as [Gunstick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4424326/gunstick) points out in a comment on the question, using `\"` *in the alternative value* to produce `"` in the output *does* work in double-quoted strings - e.g., `echo "${var:+\"Hi th\"ere\"}"` - unlike in unquoted here-docs.)
- **related expansions** `${var+...}`, `${var-...}` / `${var:-...}`, and `${var=...}` / `${var:=...}`
- Also, there's a **related oddity with respect to `\`-handling** inside double-quoted alternative values inside a double-quoted string / unquoted here-doc:  `bash` and `ksh` unexpectedly *remove* embedded `\` instances; e.g.,
  `echo "${nosuch:-"a\b"}"` unexpectedly yields `ab`, even though `echo "a\b"` in isolation yields `a\b` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37752879/45375).

I have **no explanation** for the behavior<sup>[1]</sup>
, but I can offer **pragmatic solutions** that work with all major POSIX-compatible shells (`dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`):

Note that **`"` instances are never needed for *syntactic* reasons inside the alternative value: The alternative value is *implicitly* treated like a double-quoted string**: no tilde expansion, no word-splitting, and no globbing take place, but parameter expansions, arithmetic expansions and command substitutions *are* performed.

<sup>Note that in parameter expansions involving *substitution* or *prefix/suffix-removal*, quotes *do* have syntactic meaning; e.g.: `echo "${BASH#*"bin"}"` or `echo "${BASH#*'bin'}"` - curiously, `dash` doesn't support single quotes, though.</sup>

- If you want to **surround the *entire* alternative value with quotes**, and it has  **no embedded quotes** and you want it **expanded**,
  **quote the *entire expansion***, which bypasses the problem of `"` removal from the alternative value:

  ```
  # Double quotes
  $ var=1; cat <<EOF
  "${var:+The closest * is far from   $HOME}"
  EOF
  "The closest * is far from   /Users/jdoe"
  ```

  ```
  # Single quotes - but note that the alternative value is STILL EXPANDED,
  # because of the overall context of the unquoted here-doc.
  var=1; cat <<EOF
  '${var:+The closest * is far from   $HOME}'
  EOF
  'The closest * is far from   /Users/jdoe'
  ```
- For **embedded quotes**, or to **prevent expansion of the alternative value**,
  **use an *embedded command substitution*** (unquoted, although it'll behave as if it were quoted):

  ```
  # Expanded value with embedded quotes.
  var=1; cat <<EOF
  ${var:+$(printf %s "We got 3\" of snow at   $HOME")}
  EOF
  We got 3" of snow at   /Users/jdoe
  ```

  ```
  # Literal value with embedded quotes.
  var=1; cat <<EOF
  ${var:+$(printf %s 'We got 3" of snow at   $HOME')}
  EOF
  We got 3" of snow at   $HOME
  ```

These two approaches can be combined as needed.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
In effect, the alternative value:

- behaves like an *implicitly* double-quoted string,
- `'` instances, as in regular double-quoted strings, are treated as *literals*.

Given the above,

- **it would make sense to treat embedded `"` instances as literals too, and simply pass them through, just like the `'` instances.**
  Instead, **sadly, they are *removed*, and if you try to escape them as `\"`, the `\` is retained too** (inside unquoted here-documents, but curiously not inside double-quoted strings), except in **`ksh` - the laudable exception -**, where the `\` instances *are* removed.  In **`zsh`**, curiously, trying to use **`\"` breaks the expansion altogether** (as do unbalanced *unescaped* ones in all shells).

  - More specifically, the double quotes have *no syntactic function* in the alternative value, but they are *parsed as if they did*: quote removal is applied, and you can't use (unbalanced) `"` instances in the interior without `\"`-escaping them (which, as stated, is useless, because the `\` instances are retained).

Given the implicit double-quoted-string semantics, literal `$` instances must either be `\$`-escaped, or a command substitution must be used to embed a single-quoted string (`$(printf %s '...')`).

Comment: I think embedded `"` ARE treated as literals, and then removed away when bash performs value evaluation. But that makes me curious, why prefix/suffix removal does not behave consistently. I think I'll need to look into bash source code to untangle, what is really happening...

Comment: @PatrykObara: That's precisely the inconsistency: the double quotes have no syntactic _function_ in the alternative value, but they are _parsed as if they did_: quote removal is applied, as you describe, and you can't use `"` instances in the interior without `\"`-escaping them (which is useless, because the `\ ` is retained).

Comment: @PatrykObara: The difference may be unexpected, but in the context of prefix/suffix removal and string replacement quoting _does_ serve a useful function: to distinguish pattern metacharacters (e.g., `*`) from literals (e.g., `"*"`), so I wouldn't call that an inconsistency.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior looks deliberate--it is consistent across all Bourne shells I tried (e.g. ksh93 and zsh behave the same way).

The behavior is equivalent to treating the here-doc as double-quoted *for these special expansions only*. In other words, you get the same result for

```
$ echo "${var:+"hi there"}"
hi there
$ echo "${var:+'Bye'}"
'Bye'
```

There is only a very faint hint in the POSIX spec I found that something special happens for double quoted words in parameter expansions.  This is from the [informative "Examples" section of Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> The double-quoting of patterns is different depending on where the double-quotes are placed.
>
> `"${x#*}"`
>          The <asterisk> is a pattern character.
>      `${x#"*"}`
>          The literal <asterisk> is quoted and not special.

I would read the last line as suggesting that quote removal for *double quotes* applies to the word. This example would not make sense for single quotes, and by omission, there's no quote removal for single quotes.

**Update**

I tried the FreeBSD `/bin/sh`, which is derived from an Almquist Shell. This shell outputs single and double quotes. So the behavior is no longer consistent across *all* shells, only across *most* shells I tried.

As for getting double quotes in the expansion of the word after `:+`, my take is

```
$ var=1
$ q='"'
$ cat <<EOF
${var:+${q}hi there$q}
EOF
"hi there"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat <<EOF
${var:+bare alt value is string already}
${var:+'and these are quotes within string'}
${var:+"these are double quotes within string"}
${var:+"which are removed during substitution"}
"${var:+but you can simply not substitute them away ;)}"
EOF
bare alt value is string already
'and these are quotes within string'
these are double quotes within string
which are removed during substitution
"but you can simply not substitute them away ;)"
```

Note, that here-document is not needed to reproduce this:

```
$ echo "${var:+'foo'}"
'foo'
```